# Can one buy I bonds within an HSA (Health Savings Account)?

Tags: united-states, bonds, hsa, government-bonds

I [read](https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevevernon/2021/11/29/3-ways-pre-retirees-and-retirees-can-use-us-series-i-savings-bonds/?sh=6a36a3cb7a7f):

> You can’t buy I bonds within an IRA or employer-sponsored savings plan, such as a 401(k) plan. You’ll need to buy I bonds with money that you didn’t save in these programs.

Can one buy I bonds (Series I Savings Bonds) within an HSA (Health Savings Account)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One [cannot](https://thefinancebuff.com/how-to-buy-i-bonds.html) buy I bonds within an HSA or any other tax-advantaged accounts:

> You can only use regular after-tax money to buy I Bonds. They’re not available in any tax-advantaged accounts such as 401k-type plans, IRAs, or HSAs. Nor are they available through any brokerage firms such as Fidelity, Charles Schwab, or Vanguard.